# Composer -d memory_limit parameter is ignored when its bigger then 1.5G

Tags: php, composer-php

When running composer, the command goes out of memory when reaching 1.5G of ram consumption.
**Even when passing an explicit memory_limit with 
`php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar ...`
 , it goes out of memory at 1.5G. It looks like the passed parameter is just ignored.**

When I pass a lower value (125m), it goes out of memory on that limit.
My windows machine still has memory left over, so it's not a system limitation.

version is 1.6.5. My php.ini memory limit is set to -1.

Is anyone else experiencing this? Why does composer run out of memory on 1.5G usage?

Comment: Are you sure you have set the memory limit to -1 in your php.ini file? I mean the right ini file?

Comment: I think you want `php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar`, otherwise the option will not be *consumed*  by the interpreter.

Comment: I clearly state in my question that passing -d memoty_limit=-1 seems to be ignored. Also any other value that is over 1.5G, still makes the command go out of memory when reaching 1.5G of ram.

Comment: I have set my memory_limit in the right php.ini file, when I run 
`php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;" `
It returns a value of -1 .

Comment: @nexana What you state in your question is that you use `php composer.phar -d memory_limit=-1` which is the wrong order of arguments. If you want to configure the php interpreter, the value must go *before* `composer.phar`. [Reference:](http://php.net/manual/features.commandline.options.php) `php [options] [-f] <file> [--] [args...]`

Comment: @Yoshi, also tried that, with the same result.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution, for anyone interested.

It seems that the php 32bit version for windows is hard limited to consuming 2G of ram memory. If your application goes over 2G, it stops.

The solution for me was to switch to the 64bit versions of my php install. The 64bit version has a limit of 3G memory.

Comment: @Nimeshka I'm very thankful for your effort, but your comment was posted 4 hours after I submitted my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the composer [troubleshoot](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors) page, you can see several options to overcome this issue.

You can set the `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT` environment variable before running the composer command:

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer.phar <...>
```

Or you set with a command line argument:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar <...>
```

If you have set the memory limit in your php.ini file, that value should also be taken by composer. You can see what's your current memory limit by running the following command:

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough in my question, but I clearly state that passing this argument is ignored when it is over 1.5G

Comment: Did you try running it like `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer.phar <...>` ?

Comment: Nimeshka Srimal, yes I tried setting the environment variable to -1, but with the same result.

Comment: Are you on Windows? May I know how you set the Env variable?

Comment: Yes. I set it through system settings - environment variables - new system variable

Comment: @nexana does it print `-1` if you run the command `echo %COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT%` in command prompt? If not, you can set it before you run the composer command using `set COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1` and then run `composer.phar`. I guess this should definitely work.

Comment: I did as you instructed. It indeed prints -1 as the set parameter value, but the problem remains...

Comment: That's strange. I think I've tried everything I know :) one last thing, can you tell more about the "windows machine" you use? are you running this locally? Is it 32 bit by any chance? Or is your php / apache is 32 bit? You can see if it's 32 bit / 64 bit by running, php -r "echo PHP_INT_MAX;" in a command line, or you can echo this constant in a php script. If this value is 2147483647, then it's running on 32 bit. If so, that could be the reason because by default, you know  32 bit processes are limited to 2GB of max ram. So please check that. If it is not the case, then i have no idea ;)